# How to deploy a TypeORM backend to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have a backend API made in TypeORM which connects to a MySQL database and is used by a React app frontend which I have already deployed in AWS Amplify. How do I deploy my backend to AWS so my frontend can connect to it?

Comment: this is of interest to me if by chance you have the code on Github :-)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this. The only solution I found that was 100% reliable was to just create an EC2 machine and run my TypeORM project from there. Additionaly I needed to create a Gateway API to enable HTTPS calls from the ReactJS front end.